How to get row of second tbody in an HTML table
I have three tbody in a table an am able to hide first and second tr in first tbody using following code


$("table.ms-formtable tr:first").hide();
$("table.ms-formtable tr:nth-child(2)").hide();
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='ms-formtable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>tbody 1 row 1 cell 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>tbody 1 row 2 cell 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>tbody 2 row 1 cell 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>tbody 2 row 1 cell 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>tbody 3 row 1 cell 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>tbody 3 row 1 cell 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



But how do I hide a certain tr in second tbody?

Use a more precise selector. table.ms-formtable > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(1) targets 1st row of 2nd tbody, for example.

I made you the [mcve] you could have made too. I had to fix some spelling

Maybe you can try to run the following:
$("table.ms-formtable tbody:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(2)").hide();

The tbody:nth-child(2) specifies the 2nd tbody.
